# mod_rewrite: GET variables are wiped out

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule,

> RewriteEngine On 
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ci.php?/$1 [L]

The above was wiping out the GET parameters. After reading some posts on here, I used the [QSA] parameter with hopes that the GET variables will be appended to the url. But it isn't working.

> RewriteEngine On 
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ci.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

I am using codeigniter and I am not sure why my rule has to be ci.php?/$1 (meaning, why its not ci.php?page=$1 or something like that). But that is the only thing that works. And I suspect that appending the GET variables to such a URL is not working out.

How do I get out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed this was swapping the QSA and L in the last line.

- RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ci.php?/$1 [QSA,L]